# Android: Animation will not stop when activity is closed using home key or back

Tags: android, animation

I think I have found most posts on this and although I feel I am doing everything OK, when you have an activity with an animation I am finding looking at the cpu usage that the animation is still running when the activity is in the background with a cpu usage between 0.64% and 1.5%.  When I disable the animation I find the cpu goes to 0 so proved that is the culprit.

Thanks for any help you can provide as currently banging my head against a wall and I am sure this is something pretty ridiculous that I am doing wrong.

The animation should run all the time the activity is visible so on onCreate I do the following:

```
  ImageView mobilePhone = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageHandHeldMobile);
  tapPhoneOnTag = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this,    R.anim.mobile_nfc_scan);
  tapPhoneOnTag.setTarget(mobilePhone);
  tapPhoneOnTag.start();
```

In onPause I have the following code:

```
 public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    tapPhoneOnTag.end();

 }
```

In onStop I have the following code:

```
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    finish();
}
```

In onResume I have the following code:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    tapPhoneOnTag.start();
}
```

The animation XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:ordering="sequentially" >
<objectAnimator
android:duration="3500"
android:propertyName="x"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="reverse"
android:valueFrom="200"
android:valueTo="380"
android:valueType="floatType" />
</set>
```

This activity is launched from the main activity using this code:

```
private void tagviewer() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, TagViewer.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The manifest file defining the activity looks like this:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        android:label="@string/tag_viewer"

        android:parentActivityName="com.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        android:screenOrientation = "portrait">>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="Home" />
    </activity>
```